# Intellij Idea - Github VCS not showing all directories

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

I had this issue for a long time but haven't taken the time to publicly write it.

I'll be blut, here is are my repositories in Intellij Idea while connected to Github.

[Intellij Idea panel with repos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtOiu.png)

And here are my github repos from Github's website :

[Github panel with repos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhsX2.png)

As you can see, I'm missing some repos in Intellij Idea and I don't know why. On my other machine I was able to get all of the repos to show (naturally).
I don't know why this happens because some repos present in Intellij are public/private.

The only difference I could find was that all the ones not appearing are forked repos.

Why does this happen ? How can I get all my repos to appear ?

As a workaround I used a Github token... But I'd really prefer just to be able to clone from Intellij and not worry about the VCS.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: You can also try posting it on [IntelliJ forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200382555-IntelliJ-IDEA-Users) if you notice no/little traction.

Comment: Thanks @AsifKamranMalick ! I'll do that right away !

Comment: There was a similar issue reported before, please see:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-246955

It's worth checking whether your organization has OAuth enabled and whether sufficient permissions are granted to the token. Also you can use OAuth instead of token in IDE.